# Not able to pay on Paypal sandbox - Showing only logo instead of payment option

Tags: paypal

I've created the sandbox test account and I am trying to test the making payments by using another account. But not able to add card option nor I am able to see the payment option to log in.

After login, it's showing the only logo. Neither it's showing any error nor message.

[image]

Here is my Paypal HTML button code

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@gmail.com">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->    
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png"
    alt="Buy Now">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have the request / response for your initial call that you can share ?

Comment: @RahulDighe I've updated the paypal html button code

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/ ? have you referred to this at all ?

Comment: @RahulDighe I've checked the document already. I think, this is Paypal's upgraded version but we are implementing an old button that will redirect paypal's site.

Comment: something is strange. it works for me . can you change - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://www.sandboxpaypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and maybe also add the item name line -   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12oz. Bottle"> - + can you try on another browser + check developer console if you see any errors ?